# Help in (re)designing my Swing application

Tags: java, application-design, swing

I have developed a Swing application that controls execution of several scripts like jobs. I need to display the interim output of the jobs concurrently. I have followed MVC while writing the application. The application is working as expected. But off late I have the following requirements in hand:

1. A few of the script jobs need special user privileges to execute so as to access specialized resources. There seems to be no way in Java to impersonate as a different user while running an application.[[examined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581396/run-java-application-as-a-different-user-login)]. Also trying to run the Swing application as a scheduled task in windows is not helping.
2. Once started the jobs should be running even if the user logs off after starting the jobs. I am thinking of separating the execution logic from the UI and run that as a service; and introduce JMS in between the two layers so as to store/retrieve the interim the output.

Note: I need to run this application on windows.

Any ideas on meeting my requirements, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I even tried starting my application using a .NET utility which impersonates before starting my application, but without any luck. The javaw process still runs under the user who has logged in.

Comment: Java is probably not the language for this type of application. Is there some reason you can't use an existing job scheduling software application like Quartz?

Comment: I need to display all information about the jobs running in the background in a GUI. The jobs have dependencies among themselves. I am not able to see how Quartz job solves my problem of requiring the jobs to be executed with a different user's credentials. Moreover my jobs will always be started manually at first and there is no need of repetition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I designed my application as a 3 part architecture. A GUI part, a model part which runs as a windows service using IBM service wrapper and a JMS messaging middleware to communicate between the previous 2 components.